# How to concatenate two columns from MySQL DataTable in the Datagrid View of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, mysql-workbench, datagridviewcolumn

I'm sorry if my question is quite simple, I am a college student trying to explore database connections in visual studio. I was able to display values from my database table in the datagrid view but I was wondering how to concatenate two columns and make them appear as one in the textbox. Thank you very much to anyone who can help me. I am currently using the C# language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the column in MySql and use the Alias as biding to the grid. So in the below example, you can bind the grid column with `Address.`

```
SELECT CustomerName, CONCAT(Address, " ", PostalCode, " ", City) AS Address
FROM Customers;
```